# Java: input.nextline passing and not entering the vlaue error

Tags: java, string

I made Bank Account class:

```
package bankaccount;


public class BankAccount {

    long accountNo=0+(long)(Math.random()*999999999999999999L);
    String name;
    double balance=0;
    double amount;



    public double deposit(double amount){
        balance=balance+amount;
        return balance;

    }

    public double withdraw(double amount){
        balance=balance-amount;
        return balance;

    }

    public void BalancInquiry(){
        System.out.println("your ammount of balance is: "+balance+" SAR ");
    }

    public void PrintInfo(){
        System.out.println("------------------------------------\n");
        System.out.println("Account Nymber: "+accountNo);
        System.out.println("Account Name: "+name);
        System.out.println("Balance: "+balance+" SAR");
    }

}
```

in the driver class I have problem that the input.nextLine() for the name is doesnt let me insert the value ! it pass it to the next lines, this is the output:

```
 run: Do you want to create an Count?   if yes choose 1   if no  choose
 2 1

 Creating your account: Enter your name:  You have finished createing
 your account!   Thank you. 
 ------------------------------------

 choose operation do you want to do:
  1 Add new palance   
  2 withdraw palance
  3 show your palance
  4 print your account info
```

and this is the driver class code:

```
package bankaccount;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class BankAccountTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       int AccountMaking = 0;
       int newPalance=0;
       int operation=0;

        System.out.println("Do you want to create an Count? \n if yes choose 1 \n if no  choose 2");
        AccountMaking=input.nextInt();



        switch(AccountMaking){
            case 1:
             BankAccount account1= new BankAccount(); 
             System.out.println("Creating your account:");
             System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
             account1.name=input.nextLine();


            System.out.println("You have finished createing your account! \n Thank you. ");


             System.out.println("------------------------------------\n");

             System.out.println("choose operation do you want to do: \n 1 Add new palance \n 2 withdraw palance"
                     + " \n 3 show your palance\n 4 print your account info");
             operation=input.nextInt();
             switch (operation){
                 case 1:
                 System.out.println("Enter the amount of balance you want to Add: ");
                 account1.amount=input.nextDouble();
                 System.out.println(account1.deposit(account1.amount));
                 System.out.println("Your new planace has added! \n Thank you. ");
                 break;

                 case 2:
                     System.out.println("Enter the amount of balance you want to withdraw: ");
                     account1.amount=input.nextDouble();
                     System.out.println(account1.withdraw(account1.amount));
                     System.out.println("Your new planace has withdrawn! \n Thank you. ");
                     break;

                 case 3:
                     account1.BalancInquiry();
                     System.out.println("Your balance has shown! \n Thank you. ");
                     break;

                 case 4:
                     account1.PrintInfo();
                     break;

                 default:
                     System.out.println("we don't have this operation, choose one of the number of operations above! \n Thank ");

                     break;
             }



            default:
            System.out.println("Thank you for using this application \n    GoodBye!    ");


    }
    }   
}
```

note: I use nextLine() because I want to enter the full name, I tries to use next but I has error shown when I enter a full neme and works only for first name , this is the error shown when I use next() for more than one word:

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
run:
Do you want to create an Count? 
 if yes choose 1 
 if no  choose 2
Zahraa Maher
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at bankaccount.BankAccountTest.main(BankAccountTest.java:14)
/Users/Zahraa_maher/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 6 seconds)
```

I hope you can help me to find the solution :(

Comment: Instead of input.nextLine() use input.next(), that should solve the problem.

Comment: I have Added, but it doesnet let me but more than one word, if I want to write the full name for Example Zahraa Maher , the re is error shown for me like that:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at bankaccount.BankAccountTest.main(BankAccountTest.java:33)
/Users/Zahraa_maher/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 9 seconds)

Comment: put input.nextLine();

after 

AccountMaking=input.nextInt();


So when you continue reading with input.nextLine() you receive the "\n" Enter key.

Comment: still it has the problem , can you edit the code for me ?